# Javascript: output youtube video title in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, youtube

```
var ytApiKey = "AIzaSyAnyNiFEIbwKMBREKM3N4LCIMLRwEJLN9M";
var videoId = "{SIMPLETEXT}";

$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=" + videoId + "&key=" + ytApiKey, function(data) {
document.getElementById('ytvdetails').innerHTML = (data.items[0].snippet.title);
});
```

That code, currently, only prints the title of the last youtube video on the first post containing the script.

[image]

How would I do it so it prints its corresponding title for each post?

I've already tried this.parentNode and this.parentNode.parentNode (the script is inside the div that is supposed to display the video title)

Comment: Pls write the output so far

Comment: I've added an image of what happens, if that helps.

Comment: Ok. And what's inside the "data"? Can you place the resulting content of "data" (like `console.log(data)`)?

Comment: Are there multiple elements using the id `ytvdetails` ? Because you can't assign an id more than once, that's what classes are for.

Comment: @spenibus When I changed it to class="ytdetails" and getElementsByClassName('ytdetails'), it didn't work at all.

Mr.Web I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Well, you do need to uniquely identify elements if you do multiple requests. You could try adding the video id to the element id so you could do something like `getElementById('ytvdetails_'+videoId)`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!